# Roles of noun phrases in passive transformations

Tags: passive, grammatical-object, noun-phrases

> They gave him a book.
>  He was given a book.

In the first sentence above, "They" is the subject, "him" is the indirect object, and "a book" is the direct object.

In the second sentence, "He" is the subject.

For some reason I hesitate to call "a book" the direct object in the second sentence.

Does my hesitation have some justification that expertise in syntax can identify? If so, what would one call it instead of a direct object?

Comment: I feel it is an object, but I am no expert in syntax.

Comment: This kind of transformation is possible in English, but not in many languages. I'm not sure that it is helpful to call it _passive_.

Comment: It's explained on [English Grammar and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169710/15299). Short version: there are two rules, Passive and Dative, which can interact in several ways. They're all grammatical and they mean the same thing, like syntactic rules always do.

Comment: @jlawler : ok, One of them is a passive transformation and the other a dative transformation. The escaped convict in Charles Dickens's novel _Great Expectations_ had been subjected to all forms of physical abuse known to jailers, and he explained that as follows: "I've been done everything to." I've thought of this as a "prepositional passive with a transitive verb." Would you call it something else?

Comment: @jawler : Or: "This table was eaten lunch at."

Comment: Or _This bed was slept in by George Washington_. Sure. Transitivizing prepositions do transitivize; that's what they're for. See _look at, listen to, think about,_ etc. They can be parsed [look [at X]] or [[look at] X], speaker's choice.

Comment: All that's happened is the indirect object of the active ("him") is externalised, i.e. it becomes the subject of the passive. "A book" is still the direct object of "give".

Comment: All that's happened is the indirect object of the active ("him") is externalised, i.e. it has become the subject of the passive. But "a book" is still the direct object of "give" in the passive -- what else could it be?

Comment: @jlawler : "The bed was slept in." has an intransitive verb; "The table was eaten lunch at." has a transitive verb. And that kind of transformation with a transitive verb seems to be seldom seen except with phrasal verbs. (But Charles Dickens used it at least once.)